# Stable Diffusion: Is it possible to merge specific token weights from one model into another?

Tags: models, diffusion-models

I have three models: A, B, C

I merged A+C and B+C together.

A+C gives me great results for certain things but is not so good with specific other things. B+C is great with things that A+C is not, but performs less great in other areas.

I was wondering if there is a way to merge specific types of tokens from A+C into B+C so that it performs better with these things.

I read about token merging, but it seems to be something else (about performance).

Is there a way to achieve that only specific things get merged from one model into another?

Comment: I hardly think that linear interpolation of solutions on a non convex function might have any meaning